# Blurred rounded corners in shape Android

Tags: android, shapes, rounded-corners

I'm using shape as a background which looks like this:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    >
    <corners
        android:radius="24dp" />

    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/dark_gray" />

    <solid android:color="@color/sepia_bright" />


</shape>
```

to create rounded rectangle. Here is how the corner of that rectangle looks like:

[image]

as you can see, everything is little blurred. I can make lines sharper when I turn off hardware acceleration (hardwareAccelerated="false")

[image]

but that corner looks still very bad, even on higher density displays. And last weird thing is that it looks much better on phones than tablets with same densities.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML drawables are crap in Android. There is nothing you could do except draw that yourself with canvas. E.g. you could implement a custom Drawable where you draw that yourself.

Comment: Ouu... I don't get why canvas is better executed than shape drawables.  But why is it ok on phones?

Comment: With canvas you could cheat a little making the lines double so big and scalling the result down.

Comment: Since I'am using this only for a simple border I found simpler solution with 9-patch.